# upgrade windows server 2012 R2 to windows server 2022

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, upgrade

we want to upgrade our windows server 2012 R2 to windows server 2022, looks like we would have to do a clean install.

I have some hard drives (HDD & SSD) which have data, if we remove all the data drives, install windows server 2022 on a new drive and connect the data drives back to the server, would the drives be recognised by the new windows server version? or we would need to format all data drives and restore them with a backup post the server upgrade.

Any help on this would be really great, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

2012R2->2019->2022 is an allowed path using inplace-upgrades (this does not require a server 2019 license). Normally, forums are full of warnings "don't you dare to inplace-upgrade", while my experience is very good (do that all the time). If this server is easy to reinstall cleanly, of course a clean setup is always preferred.

Comment: My apologies. Just learned by trying that you may even upgrade directly 2012R2->2022!

Comment: I've had good experiences with in-place upgrades as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any (supported) Windows Server will recognize any NTFS/ReFS/exFAT volumes. Even when attached later.

When using a standalone server and not a domain member, you may need to reset your NTFS ACL on it, though.